# Spring boot application crashes on AWS randomly

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I'm uncertain if I'm overlooking something.

My application randomly stops on AWS, and I can't find any relevant information in the logs. When I inspect the running threads in the terminal of the EC2 instance, it shows almost 0 percentage, and at that moment, there's no active usage. However, CloudWatch indicates very high CPU usage.

Even if i monitor it localy in the intellij shows 0 %. Heap memory usage is close to zero too.

Am I misunderstanding something? Do you have any insights into what might be causing these random stops or issues with the CloudWatch metrics?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you confirm your application is the process that takes the high cpu? Maybe it's another process in your ec2 instance?
Do you run your app using some java flags, e.g. `-Xms` and such?

Comment: I am using this command : nohup java -jar application.jar --spring.profiles.active=prod >> output.log 2>&1 &. If i monitor in the EC2 terminal using top -h there is not even a procces that uses more than 1%. If i monitor only the threads of the runnin applications (top -H -p (PID of application) ) still every thread is at 0.0 ~ 0.5 %.

Comment: That CloudWatch screenshot shows CPU usage going from about 1% to 1.76%. That is not "very high" CPU usage. That is a tiny blip. Very high usage would be over 80% or 90%. I don't think the CPU usage is the issue, it is just an indication that a tiny increase in CPU usage occurs just before the crash. Your Spring Boot logs probably have more relevant information into what the issue is. The logs should either say why it crashed, or what exit signal it received. If you aren't seeing that, turn up your Spring logging level.

Comment: Then maybe I misunderstood the metric system. They suggested that 1.00 is equal to 100%, and it just upscales itself somehow. Never mind. I checked the log file, but there is nothing about the crash. What should be the best way to log these crashes?